# Operate on pairs of rows of a data frame

Tags: r

I've got a data frame in R, and I'd like to perform a calculation on all pairs of rows. Is there a simpler way to do this than using a nested for loop?

To make this concrete, consider a data frame with ten rows, and I want to calculate the difference of scores between all (45) possible pairs.

```
> data.frame(ID=1:10,Score=4*10:1)
   ID Score
1   1    40
2   2    36
3   3    32
4   4    28
5   5    24
6   6    20
7   7    16
8   8    12
9   9     8
10 10     4
```

I know I could do this calculation with a nested for loop, but is there a better (more R-ish) way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here another solution using `combn`:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:10,Score=4*10:1)
cm <- combn(df$ID,2)
delta <- df$Score[cm[1,]]-df$Score[cm[2,]]
```

or more directly

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:10,Score=4*10:1)
delta <- combn(df$ID,2,function(x) df$Score[x[1]]-df$Score[x[2]])
```

Comment: Ooh, I like the combn function very much.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this on a data frame with several columns, but can't make it work. Could @teucer possibly show how do this? E.g. if there was score1, score2, score3 etc. Just to be clear, the difference between [1,2] and [2,2], not sum[1,] and sum[2,].

So you would end up with a data frame with the same number of columns as the original one, but with more rows.

Answer (score 7):

To calculate the differences, perhaps you could use

```
outer(df$Score,df$Score,"-")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
colmx = matrix(rep(df[,2], 10), ncol=10, byrow=F)
rowmx = matrix(rep(df[,2], 10), ncol=10, byrow=T)
delta = colmx - rowmx
```

Comment: ~ubuntu and i get the same answer; 'outer' is a wrapper over the matrix computation i did explicitly, which explains the performance difference between the two--for a 100 x 100 matrix, averaged over 100 trials, the built-in was only about 10% slower--given all the artifacts in measuring this sort of thing, i would say that's within the noise threshold.

Answer (score 3):

dist() is your friend.

```
dist(df$Score)
```

You can put it as a matrix :

```
as.matrix( dist(df$Score) )
```

Comment: how did i miss (another) built-in?! Anyway, nice one, +1 from me.