# R row operation line i - line j

Tags: r, line, operation

I need do to calculate the difference between consecutive lines.
Is there a clever way to do it?
The solution below works. Thanks

```
pos=data.frame(position=c(1,2,3),value=c(1.3,2.7,3.1))
     position value
  1        1   1.3
  2        2   2.7
  3        3   3.1

r=NULL; rnome=NULL 
for(i in seq(1,length(pos[,1])-1))  
    for(j in seq(i+1,length(pos[,1]))) 
        r=rbind(r,c(levels=paste0(pos$level[i],'-', pos$level[j]), dif=pos$value[j]-pos$value[i]))

> r
    levels dif  
[1,] "1-2"  "1.4"
[2,] "1-3"  "1.8"
[3,] "2-3"  "0.4"
```

Comment: Do you mean "all pairs of lines" rather than "consecutive" lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615907/operate-on-pairs-of-rows-of-a-data-frame) (first hit when googling "R difference all pairs").

Comment: it is not all pairs, position1<position2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `combn` function can help you to generalize the code a bit. This seems a bit more elegant:

```
pos <- data.frame(position=c(1,2,3),value=c(1.3,2.7,3.1))

ans <- data.frame(levels = combn(pos$position, 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "-"),
                  dif = combn(pos$value, 2, FUN = diff))
print(ans)
#  levels dif
#1    1-2 1.4
#2    1-3 1.8
#3    2-3 0.4

# Get all combinations:
comb <- expand.grid(pos$position, pos$position)
lvls <- with(comb, paste0(Var1, "-", Var2))
difs <- with(comb, Var1 - Var2)
ans2 <- data.frame(levels = lvls, dif = difs)
print(ans2)
#  levels dif
#1    1-1   0
#2    2-1   1
#3    3-1   2
#4    1-2  -1
#5    2-2   0
#6    3-2   1
#7    1-3  -2
#8    2-3  -1
#9    3-3   0
```

Comment: Tks, AEBilgrau. Is there a function to get "3-1" either? (order matters)

Comment: @Alex Your specification in the question and comments says you do not want that combination? But yes, there is a function for it. The `expand.grid` gets you all combinations. The return type of `expand.grid` functions is different though, so the code is also different. I've updated my answer.

Comment: AEBilgrau, you are right. I was curious about other solution. Tks, again.