# Max distances between all possible pairs of coordinates by group

Tags: r, max, grouping, distance

I need to find the max (absolute, not accumulated) distance from Lambert coordinates an individual ID moved.

I have the following dataset:

```
         rownum <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
         ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3)
         years <- c(1994, 1994, 1995, 1995, 1994, 1998, 1999, 1999)
         coorx <- c(160501,160507,160507,160508,160638,160402,160402,160707)
         coory <- c(202549,202727,202727,202488,202701,202586,202586,202548)
         test <- as.data.frame(cbind(rownum, ID, years, coorx, coory))
```

The points are in Lamberts 72 coordinates, thus already in euclidean distance. Therefore I know I need to use sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2) to find distances between pairs of rows. What I got stuck on is that I need to compare all rows pairwise for each separate individual to find the max distance while simultaneously doing this calculation. I.e. compare row 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4 etc. and extract max dist from this. I need to add this result to a new column (one max value for all rows per individual).

In case of only one coordinate (ID 2) then a 0 or NA can be added.

All answers I can find only do this between consecutive rows OR for the whole vector not split by group (e.g. [Operate on pairs of rows of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615907/operate-on-pairs-of-rows-of-a-data-frame)).

Any way to adapt combn, outer or dist functions for this?

An extension of this question is also to find the max distance only between years by taking the first coordinates for a given year and compare it with coordinates from the first coordinates any other year. However, the most important is the first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do that with `dplyr`. Basically, I first `group_by` ID, then, I remove the rownum and years columns using `select`. I then merge the data with itself on ID usinf `full_join`. This creates pairs of coordinates. It also creates coordinates changes from year1 to year2 and vice versa, but it's not a problem since we will only keep the `max`. Then I create a new dist column using `mutate` and finally, I only the keep the `max` distance by ID using `summarise`.

```
test <- as.data.frame(cbind(rownum, ID, years, coorx, coory))
test %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  select(ID,coorx, coory) %>% 
  full_join(.,.,by="ID") %>% 
  mutate(dist=sqrt((coorx.x-coorx.y)^2+(coory.x-coory.y)^2)) %>% 
  summarise(max_dist=max(dist,na.rm=TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID max_dist
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 239.0021
2     2   0.0000
3     3 307.3581
```

If you only want to the exercise using the first location of each year, you have to use `filter` with `row_number()==1` .

```
test <- as.data.frame(cbind(rownum, ID, years, coorx, coory))
test %>% 
  group_by(ID,years) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(row_number()==1) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  select(ID,coorx, coory) %>% 
  full_join(.,.,by="ID") %>% 
  mutate(dist=sqrt((coorx.x-coorx.y)^2+(coory.x-coory.y)^2)) %>% 
  summarise(max_dist=max(dist,na.rm=TRUE))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID max_dist
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 178.1011
2     2   0.0000
3     3   0.0000
```

Finally, here's how to do the same thing with `data.table`. I first `merge` the data with itself on ID.  Then I create a new dist column using the `:=` operator and finally, I only the keep the `max` distance by ID.

```
test <- as.data.table(cbind(ID, coorx, coory))
merged <- merge(test,test,by=c("ID"),allow.cartesian=TRUE)
merged[,dist:=sqrt((coorx.x-coorx.y)^2+(coory.x-coory.y)^2) ]
merged[,.(max_dist=max(dist,na.rm=TRUE)),by=ID]

   ID max_dist
1:  1 239.0021
2:  2   0.0000
3:  3 307.3581
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a *self-join* (SQL speak) where you `merge` dataframe onto itself for a cross join (i.e., cartesian product) of all possible combinations by ID. Then calculate distance per your formula and `aggregate` for `max` by ID:

```
merge_df <- merge(test, test, by="ID", suffixes=c("1", "2"))    
merge_df$dist <- with(merge_df, sqrt((coorx2-coorx1)^2+(coory2-coory1)^2))

max_dist <- aggregate(dist~ID, merge_df, FUN=max)
max_dist
#   ID     dist
# 1  1 239.0021
# 2  2   0.0000
# 3  3 307.3581
```

And for first years, run an aggregate on original dataframe to pick first, i.e., `head(df)[1]`, then run same process as above with self join:

```
year_df <- aggregate(.~ID + years, test, FUN=function(i) head(i)[1])

merge_df <- merge(year_df, year_df, by="ID", suffixes=c("1", "2"))
merge_df$dist <- with(merge_df, sqrt((coorx2-coorx1)^2+(coory2-coory1)^2))

max_dist <- aggregate(dist~ID, merge_df, FUN=max)
max_dist
#   ID     dist
# 1  1 178.1011
# 2  2   0.0000
# 3  3   0.0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` and `.SD`.

```
rownum <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3)
years <- c(1994, 1994, 1995, 1995, 1994, 1998, 1999, 1999)
coorx <- c(160501,160507,160507,160508,160638,160402,160402,160707)
coory <- c(202549,202727,202727,202488,202701,202586,202586,202548)
test <- as.data.frame(cbind(rownum, ID, years, coorx, coory))

library(data.table)
setDT(test)

test[,
  max(
    dist(
      .SD[1:.N, .(coorx, coory)]
    )
  ),
  by = ID
]
```